# Xcode Constraints is Difficult?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, constraints

I've programed an app and am at the final stage (layout my design) i've tried setting **the constraints**

But am facing hard times with it ...

so

Is there a way to design a layout for each device (iphone 4,5,6) and ipads separately ?

Comment: The first time you use constraints, it is painful, but you'll get the hang of it. Don't give up. I'd suggest posting a question, showing us what you want to do and we can give you tips.

Comment: Using the size  class is easiest way to manage your app. It may seems like little difficult at first but actually it is not. Or you can use 2 storyboards, one for iPhones (4,5,6 all) and one for iPads (normal, mini and pro) then not use size classes. (this means all iPhone screens will looks same with different sizes). You have to manage witch storyboards to use in the code. But it may be much better than designing separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to design all of them separately then you'll have to go the nibs(.xibs) and make a different nib for each iphone(4,5,6) and ipads but rather than I suggest you to use size classes and and then apply the necessary constants at first it'll be a little difficult but by time you'll learn how to apply the size classes and constants.
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) are the links where you'll find the best [examples](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started).

Comment: hi,
thank for all the help you gave me ... i'm gona give it a try .... but how i can design different nib for each device !?

Comment: here's your way best of luck : ) https://irawd.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/how-to-link-a-xib-file-to-a-class-and-use-2-xib-files-for-iphone4-and-iphone5/